# WSO2IS - Disable Embedded LDAP - deployment.toml

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

How can I disable Embedded Ldap on Identity Server 5.10.0 version? I'm checking conf/identity/embedded-ldap.xml and enable property is true.

```
  <EmbeddedLDAP>
    <Property name="enable">true</Property>
    <Property name="port">${Ports.EmbeddedLDAP.LDAPServerPort}</Property>
    <Property name="instanceId">default</Property>
     .....
```

I couldn't find how I can disable. If I overwrite this file when docker starts it came back to true.

Comment: Are you using a docker image downloaded from https://hub.docker.com/r/wso2/wso2is/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated? can you see a file named `embedded-ldap.xml.j2` at `<wso2is-5.10.0-home>/repository/resources/conf/templates/repository/conf/identity` location ?

Comment: I'm creating my own docker image using wso2is-5.10.0.zip downloaded from wso2 website. I have this identity.xml.j2 file in my conf directory that I use in docker-compose @Anuradha Karunarathna.

Comment: Do you have `<wso2is-5.10.0-home>/repository/resources/conf/templates/repository/conf/identity/embedded-ldap.xml.j2` file?

Comment: Yes, I have @AnuradhaKarunarathna

Comment: If it contains  `<Property name="enable">{{embedded_ldap.enable}}</Property>` under   `<EmbeddedLDAP>` you would be able to change that property via deployment.toml by using the `[embedded_ldap]
enable = false` config

Comment: It not contains <EmbeddedLDAP>. Could you tell me where I put? @AnuradhaKarunarathna

Comment: I don't have this file embedded-ldap.xml.j2 @AnuradhaKarunarathna. In this folder `wso2is-5.10.0/repository/resources/conf/templates/repository/conf/identity` only contains application-authentication.xml.j2, captcha-config.properties.j2, captcha-config.properties.j2, entitlement.properties.j2, identity-event.properties.j2 and identity.xml.j2 file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WSO2 Identity Server 5.10.0 version the file `embedded-ldap.xml.j2` doesn't come inside
`wso2is-5.10.0/repository/resources/conf/templates/repository/conf/identity` so I needed to copy the file from this link: [embedded-ldap.xml.j2](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-userstore-ldap/blob/master/features/org.wso2.carbon.ldap.server.server.feature/resources/conf/embedded-ldap.xml.j2) and put inside my configuration for docker container `conf/is-as-km/repository/resources/conf/templates/repository/conf/identity`

docker-compose.yml

```
...
volumes:
 - ./conf/is-as-km:/home/wso2carbon/wso2-config-volume
 ports:
  - "9444:9443"
...
```

After that I put the property in deployment.toml:

```
[embedded_ldap]
enable = false
```

And everything worked as shown in docker log:

```
cup-is-as-km ... NFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.uma...} - UMA Grant component activated successfully.
cup-is-as-km ... INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ldap.server.DirectoryActivator} - Embedded LDAP is disabled.
cup-is-as-km ... INFO {org.wso2.carbon.mex.internal.Of...} - Office365Support MexServiceComponent bundle activated successfully..
```

Based on the last answers and comments I reached the solution ;).

Answer (score 1):

1. If you have `<wso2is-5.10.0-home>/repository/resources/conf/templates/repository/conf/identity/embedded-ldap.xml.j2` file and it's `enable` property value under `<EmbeddedLDAP>` is templated as `{{embedded_ldap.enable}}` (shown below),

```
<EmbeddedLDAP>
    <Property name="enable">{{embedded_ldap.enable}}</Property>
    <Property name="port">${Ports.EmbeddedLDAP.LDAPServerPort}</Property>
    <Property name="instanceId">default</Property>
.....
</EmbeddedLDAP>
```

you can use the following deployment.toml config

```
[embedded_ldap]
enable = false
```

2. If the `<wso2is-5.10.0-home>/repository/resources/conf/templates/repository/conf/identity/embedded-ldap.xml.j2` file contains the `EmbeddedLDAP` config's `enable` property value as hardcoded to "true", you can change it to **false** and restat the server to change the config in `embedded-ldap.xml`.

```
<EmbeddedLDAP>
    <Property name="enable">true</Property>
    <Property name="port">${Ports.EmbeddedLDAP.LDAPServerPort}</Property>
    <Property name="instanceId">default</Property>
.....
</EmbeddedLDAP>
```

3. If you don't have `<wso2is-5.10.0-home>/repository/resources/conf/templates/repository/conf/identity/embedded-ldap.xml.j2` file, the property value changes in `embedded-ldap.xml` won't be replaced once the server is restarted.

Comment: I don't have this file embedded-ldap.xml.j2. I was looking on identity.xml.j2 :(. Where can I find to put in my project?

Comment: That particular file can be found here.https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-userstore-ldap/blob/master/features/org.wso2.carbon.ldap.server.server.feature/resources/conf/embedded-ldap.xml.j2 It is not available in the 5.10 GA pack. It has been shipped in the product with 5.11. I'm not sure whether adding this file will work for you. The mentioned 3rd option should work. If you don't have that j2 file, changes done in repository/conf/identity/embedded-ldap.xml shouldn't be overwritten when the server starts up

Answer (score 0):

In WSO2 Identity Server 5.10.0 the configurations are managed by a centralized toml file which is called as **deployment.toml**. We can add the following configuration to the deployment.toml file which is located in **<IS_HOME>/repository/conf** directory.

```
[embedded_ldap]
enable = false
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it keeps the property enable to true. Where did you find this property on wso2 documentation? Because I couldn't find in any place.